# Can the spatial features(information of Input image) disappear in Fully Connected Layers?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, cnn

I also know the spatial features disappear at pooling layer. I just want to know the spatial features can disappear at FC layer (through the above procedure).

Comment: What is the "above procedure"?